# Access issues with one - and only one - network folder

Tags: windows, shared-directory

I have a home NAS and a Windows 10 PC. I have enabled the following services in the stock control panel: UPnP/DLNA, SMB, FTP, and WebDAV. I am able to access all the folder/files using any of these services except for one subfolder and that only from Windows Explorer (i.e. SMB). That is, trying to access `\\SHARE\folder\subfolder1\subfolder2` will give me `Windows cannot access` error in Windows Explorer, while I'm able to access it via ftp, DAV, and through stock web file browser.

Here's the interesting part: I tried changing the ownership and the permissions in the Security properties panel (right click > Properties > Security). First error I get is that permissions are incorrectly ordered. I am able to proceed by acknowledging, and I'm then given the option to Reorder them, that I also can get through. But trying to actually change the owner or the principal or any other ownership relation for that matter always results in `Failed to enumerate objects in the container. Access is denied` error - always, not matter what I try.

Trying to `takeownership` or `icacls` just returns `Access is denied`, regardless of my admin privileges.

There is nothing funny or strange in the `subfolder2` name, no special characters.

How can I troubleshoot this and figure out what to do to be able to enter the folder via Windows Explorer/SMB?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so the most random and bizarre thing happened. I will leave a reply here in case someone else has a similar problem.

As I mentioned, one of the services I had enabled on the NAS was FTP. I logged into the share folder via FTP (using Windows Explorer - I just typed the `ftp://local.address/folder/subfolder1` in the address bar. I right clicked on the `subfolder2` that was giving me the issues and the dialog that came up was much simpler than the standard Windows Explorer properties dialog. As in, I saw only one tab and in it, among other information, the check-boxes to set read/write permissions for different users. The only checkbox that was not ticked off was actually `Read` for `All` users. I ticked it off and suddenly everything works. I can now access `subfolder2` right from the Windows Explorer, just like any other folder.

All in all, I find this all pretty idiotic, but I'm out of the woods. I hope this helps others as well.